# Can you name a variable without declaring it?

Tags: r, variables

When I'm using functions that output tables, I like to see some variable names. However, I'm a very lazy man who doesn't want to write three lines when I write one. Take a simple function like `tail`. What I like to do is:

```
boxes<-1:50
names(boxes)<-paste("Box",boxes)
tail(boxes)
```

and this will get me the output:

```
Box 45 Box 46 Box 47 Box 48 Box 49 Box 50 
    45     46     47     48     49     50
```

However, that felt like too much work to me. The bulk of my code was spent naming `boxes`. What I wanted to write was something like

```
tail((1:50);names(1:50)<-paste("Box",1:50))
```

Is anything like this possible for when I want to name a variable without declaring it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `setNames` without creating an object

```
setNames(1:50, paste0("Box", 1:50))
```

---

Or another option is `enframe/deframe`

```
library(tibble)
deframe(enframe(sprintf("Box%d", 1:50))[2:1])
```

Comment: To get the required output `tail(setNames(1:50, paste("Box", 1:50)))`

Comment: @MarceloFernandoBefumo Thanks. yes, you are right.  I didn't wrap it with `tail` as the names part seems to be an issue for the OP.